# Could Amazon S3 (& AWS generally) Services Be Affected by DDOS Botnet Attacks Against Amazon.com

Tags: amazon-s3, botnet

With groups planning to attack Amazon, does anyone have an idea if customers who use their Cloud Services could be affected?  I get that they are trying to shut down the retail side, but do you think this would affect web apps that use AWS?

Last, is there something/strategy that web app companies can take, if such an attack was directed at AWS?

Comment: You think amazon hasn't been attacked before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I wouldn't suppose so. AWS and amazon (as in: the webshop) are two completely different services and are on different servers. An attack on the frontpage would be quite sufficient though, as it is a major income for the organisation.